Boot strap a remote backup
I'm setting up an offsite backup of my NAS,(truenas scale if it is relevant), the remote system is being built on site so I don't have physical access to it yet, but I will travel to it soon.
I would like to setup the ZFS sync on block level and take advantage of the ZFS snapshot diff features. I have seen several examples where a full backup is created over the network but this will take several months to complete.
I would like to use sneakernet for the initial setup and pack a disk with my full data when going. Preferably this disk would be part of the final pool on the backup system aswell.
How should I do this?
Current Vdev is RAIDZ1 with 4 disks, and I plan to use a similar configuration on the remote system Is it a problem if the remote system uses smaller disks (don't need to backup some of the data)
